# Open all links with jQuery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/Javascript" src="includes/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/Javascript">
$('a').click(function() {
  window.open($(this).attr('href') );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<a href="somepage.html">Somepage</a>
<br />
<a href="somepage.html">Somepage</a>
<br />
<a href="somepage.html">Somepage</a>
<br />
<a href="somepage.html">Somepage</a>
<br />
<a href="somepage.html">Somepage</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to open all links found in the page with jQuery .load().
But my code doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('a').each(function() {
      window.open($(this).attr('href') );
    });
});
```

[**click**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is actually the action of clicking the HTMLElement. [**each**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is a loop through them.

And wrapping everything in `$();` tells jQuery,

> "Hey don't you run me until everything is ready. I want all DOM
>   elements addressable."

It is short hand for `$(document).ready` [**[doc]**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Oops, I meant `code`$('content').load($(this).sttr('href'));.

Comment: That's definitely not my homework. Just a starter to jQuery and trying to get code working.

Comment: Use $('#content') and not $('content')

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    $("#content").load($(this).attr('href') );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This code will make it so that when a user clicks on a link on your page, instead of going to the page, the contents of that page will be loaded into your `content` div.  `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default action of the link (leaveing the page) and keep the user on your page.

Now, the problem with this is that once you have clicked one link, any content loaded into the div will not have this code applied.  You can get around this by using event delegation with jquery's `on` (or delegate in older jquery versions).

```
$("#content").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    $("#content").load($(this).attr('href') );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This code will work on all links within `#content`, those there initially as well as those loaded later.